# How do i run two application run in one module

Tags: vba, excel

The two codes do not run together at the same time. How?
My code for class module

```
Private sub-App_workbooknewsheet (byval wb as workbook, byval sh as object)
Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Open_It"
Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Change"
End sub
```

Open_it

```
   Sub Open_it()
' Open the workbook from its actual folder
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\ASUS User\Desktop\MP\source.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Change

```
 Sub Change()
    Columns(2).AutoFit
    Rows().AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: `How?` - Because VBA is not asynchronous.

Comment: If this is all your code is, why not use one sub? Your second sub isn't qualifying what sheet to run on also which can be problematic

Comment: i want to run on all sheet

Answer (score 0):

You are making it way too hard. You only need one macro that loops through all the worksheets in `source.xlsm`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\ASUS User\Desktop\MP\source.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Columns(2).AutoFit
        ws.Rows().AutoFit
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```